# arrow key movement stops

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently running into an issue in which I have a table with rows and columns for a grading system. Students down the y axis and grades along the x . Once my down arrow hits row 6, it will not go down any further. Left and right are no problem at all. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!!

```
function keyDown(keyname,e){

    if (e.keyCode == 37){// Left Arrow

        var NewKeyname = parseInt(keyname) - 10;
        var intColNum = NewKeyname;         

    }

    if (e.keyCode == 38){// Up Arrow

        var NewKeyname = parseInt(keyname) - 1;
        var intColNum = NewKeyname;     

    }

    if (e.keyCode == 39) {// Right Arrow

        var NewKeyname = parseInt(keyname) + 10;
        var intColNum = NewKeyname;     

    } //Down Arrow

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {// Down Arrow

        var NewKeyname = parseInt(keyname) + 1;
        var intColNum = NewKeyname;     

    } //Down Arrow

    var setText = intColNum;    
    document.getElementById(setText).focus();       // Focus on the textbox
}
```

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to inspect this code. I don't understand the logic, and I bet some things will be made clear if you assert the code you think is being run is actually being run.

Comment: me either, I have spent the last two days trying to decipher php code that someone wrote 8 years ago. Supposedly it worked at some point. thanks though

Comment: What is `keyname`? Can you add the HTML? How is adding 1 to `keyname` supposed to get you the ID of the next row?

Comment: it seems pretty obvious that the IDs on row 7 are not  1 more than the IDs on row 6. Using sequential IDs in a dynamically-sized table is probably not a good approach. Why don't you give IDs of the form `row-M-col-N`?

Comment: Did you mean PHP or Javascript? Make sure the tags are correct.